# How do i stop my page from scrolling down once it is finished loading?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a php page that runs a bash script and its output is printed on my page. I use the following function to display the output:

```
function showOutput()
{
    var server=$('#serverSelect').val();
    $.ajax({
    url: '/marketplace/static/php/web/deployment.php',
    dataType: 'text',
    data : {
            "getOutput" :"getOutput",   
    },
    type:'POST',
    success:function(result){   
        $('#result').html(result);
        window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
        if(buildStatus==1)
        {
            showOutput();
        }
        else if(end==0)
        {
            end=1;
            setTimeout(showOutput, 10000);
        }
    }
    });
}
```

The window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight) is added so that the page scrolls to bottom as new content keeps getting printed on the page. But even when the page has stopped loading and no new content is being added, it keeps going down. If i scroll up, it auto scrolls to bottom again. What is the issue here? Any help will be appreciated.

The html where the data is being displayed:

```
<div id="result" class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
    <p ng-bind='revision'></p>
    </div>
```

Comment: When is `showOutput()` being called? Did you check your network inspector to make sure no more requests were coming in?

Comment: Well, `showOutput()` is called from whithin itself, so as long `buildStatus == 1`, the function will call itself again and again.

Comment: So basically, it is being scrolled down because the the function keeps calling itself. I did check about the network requests, i will check about showOutput. Thank you for the prompt reply